# Slick print list of tables

Tags: slick

I want to print a list of tables from the database I connect to via JDBC but cannot figure out how to do this.  I have tried using `MTable.getTables` and `defaultTables`, thanks

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent._
import com.typesafe.config.{ ConfigFactory, Config }

object SlickTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    """
      |mydb = {
      |  driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      |  slickDriver = com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
      |  url="jdbc:sqlserver://#############"
      |  properties = {
      |    databaseName = "######"
      |    user = "#######"
      |    password = "########"
      |  }
      |  numThreads = 10
      |}
    """.stripMargin


    val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")


    ???

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways of doing this, but following the layout of the code you had in your question, this works for Slick 3.1 (and using freeslick profiles, because I don't have the slick extensions SQLServer lib).

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext}


object SlickTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = """
    |mydb = {
    |
    |  driver = "freeslick.MSJDBCSQLServerProfile$"
    |  db {
    |    driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    |    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:2008"
    |    properties = {
    |      databaseName = "freeslicktest"
    |      user = "sa"
    |      password = "FreeSlick"
    |    }
    |  }
    |}
    """.stripMargin
    val dbConfig = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("mydb", ConfigFactory.parseString(config))
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    Await.result(dbConfig.db.run(dbConfig.driver.defaultTables), Duration.Inf).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

produces this result for a database with one table called USERS in it.

```
*** (c.z.hikari.HikariDataSource) HikariCP pool mydb.db is starting.
MTable(MQName(freeslicktest.dbo.USERS),TABLE,null,None,None,None)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you.  I assume the use of defaultTables means that if you are connecting via JDBC to a DB that does not have a native slick driver you cannot access the table list?

Comment: Under the covers, defaultTables is just iterating through results from the JDBC DatabaseMetaData calls. But if you want to use Slick, then you will need a concrete Slick implementation for the database and as a result, that will implement defaultTables.
Are you using a database that isn't supported by Slick?

Comment: We need to connect to a number of databases across the business. I am pretty sure most will fall into the SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 buckets but maybe we will find something else later.  But I will worry about that when it happens.  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work for 3.2.3. What's the alternative for  3.2?